# Sonarqube stage in jenkins pipeline fails with 403 error

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job which keeps failing on Sonar Quality Gate stage with the below error:

```
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 403 on http://illinXXXX:XXXXX/api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=XXXXXXXX
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:34)
```

What's more strange, another pipeline from the same MS, is passing that stage.
They both are using the same Sonarquebe user and token, and the same stage syntax.

Sonarqube version: 6.7.1 (build 35068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem:
The execution user/group had permissions to run  “Execute Analysis”
Solution:
Update the default template with permissions and push to projects (Bulk Apply Template)

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATE*
I'm not entirely sure what arielma is saying in the comment marked as the answer, but! checking the box for execute analysis got me passed the 403 issue. Permissions are located under project settings (top right of page next to project information) select groups (near search bar and the All | Users buttons in the list header) then check the appropriate execute analysis check box.